# Losing random folders on my Debians

Tags: linux, debian, backup, debian-wheezy

I'm using an updated Debian stable 6 and 7 on a few VPSs and also on a Raspberry.

I'm losing folders and stuff I've installed, e.g., Mongodb. I had to restart my VPS after updates and Mongodb was not present anymore. The same happens with some folders cloned from github with settings included. Folders disappear or become empty, except for the `.git` folder.

I'm not doing a lot of things on these different machines (mail server, IRC server, sandbox server for webapp), except `apt-get update` & `apt-get upgrade -y` sometimes.

The thing is, I don't know what to do to detect changes. I do duplicity backup on all of them after having had this problem twice.

I thought it was an HDD failure but it looks strange on 2 different VPSs and Raspberry and on very specified files and folder.

If you have any ideas, I would like to understand how something can work properly and disappear after reboot, like Mondodb ->

```
root@machine:~# find / -name mongo
```

returns nothing. Same with a github folder.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to monitor filesystem changes.

The simplest solution I can think of would be to run the find command on the whole filesystem and save it's output to a text file. You can do this again at some later point.

Now you can run a diff on the two text files and see what has changed on the filesystem.

For a more elegant solution you might have a look at [tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/) which has specific functionality for monitoring filesystem changes.

A tutorial to setup tripwire on ubunutu / debian is available at [how to use tripwire to detect server intrusions on an ubuntu vps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-tripwire-to-detect-server-intrusions-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

An example tripwire rule for your mongo folder might be:

```
(
  rulename = "User filesystem changes",
  severity = $(SIG_HI)
)
{
        /path/to/folder                -> $(SEC_CONFIG) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is I know files disapear and I really don't thinks it's due to instrusions. Tripwire seems a good start but my problem seems more related to problem after reboot.

Comment: Have you checked that the mounted filesystem is not a tmpfs? That might be cleared on reboot. Other than a service or something executing in rc.local, I can't think of anything that would selectively delete files on a reboot. Perhaps try creating a new file in a place where you don't expect things to be deleted and mount that file as a filesystem. See http://www.walkernews.net/2007/07/01/create-linux-loopback-file-system-on-disk-file/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No tmpfs only simfs (because i'm behing openVZ). The file deleted are for example in /home/myname/folder/folderdeleted  Looks strange.